# Change collapse panel content with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I Have list of projects , in each project there is a number of tasks, my idea is to use a collapse panel where the title is the name of the project and the content is the information of the tasks, the only problem I'm facing is the id of the elements so at the end, the result is mixed here is my code :

```
 <div ng-repeat= "projet in projetsactifs track by $index" >
 <div class="panel-group" id="accordion{{$index}}">
 <div class="panel panel-info">
 <div class="panel-heading">
 <h4 class="panel-title">
 <a  href="#{{$index}}l" ng-click="tasks(projet.IdProjet)" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion{{$index}}" >
 {{projet.NomProjet}}</a>
 </h4>
 </div>
  <div id="{{$index}}l" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
  <div class="panel-body">
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
      <thead>
      <tr>
      <th>Task</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>price (€/day)</th>   
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="tache in tachelistes | orderBy: 'NomTache'">
      <td>{{tache.NomTache}}</td>
      <td>{{tache.Delai | date : 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
      <td>{{tache.CoutParJour}}</td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div> 
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Controller :

```
$scope.tasks=function(id){
             Tache.getTachbyProjectID(id).then(function(response){
              $scope.tachelistes=response.data.tachelistes;
             });
         }
```

Here is a plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/JMJU3YfPJkQwBfDyS6E0?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first issue (The one where you need to filter the tasks per project) you can use the built-in [filter pipe](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) in the loop like so:

```
<tr ng-repeat="tache in tachelistes | filter: {projet_id:projet.IdProjet} | orderBy: 'NomTache'">
```

The `projet.IdProjet` field value will be matched to the `projet_id` field value and elements that do not match are skipped from the loop.

To toggle the panels, it is better to use [ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow). This will show or hide an element in the DOM based on an expression or function call. Like this for example;

```
ng-show="hiddenBody[$index]"
```

This will match the hiddenBody array at index `$index`. When evaluated to truthy, the element on which `ng-show` is defined will be made visible.

> The ngShow directive shows or hides the given HTML element based on
>   the expression provided to the ngShow attribute.

Instead of trying to filter the task array onClick, I simply define the value for hiddenBody on click. `ng-click="hiddenBody[$index] = !hiddenBody[$index]"`.

Check the **Plunker** where I made the modifications [**here**](https://plnkr.co/edit/UNlQZJ6iS1lqImExhhIy?p=preview).

Comment: Thank you this is working , only i had to change `ng-click="hiddenBody[$index] = !hiddenBody[$index]"` to `ng-click="hiddenBody[$index] = hiddenBody[$index]" ` and `ng-show="!hiddenBody[$index]"`

Comment: I was under the impression that you wanted to toggle the task panel per project if you click on the project title which is what my code does. But I'm glad it works out for you with your own changes added. You are welcome.